# The correct way to bundle CSS modules

Tags: css, reactjs, rollup, rollupjs, css-modules

I have a weird thing happening when my css modules are exported with the `* as styles` becomes inaccessible when I bundle my code and use it in other repo's.

The response from styles when bundled:

```
{default: {... my class names} }
```

When I change my code to `import styles from '...'` it works when bundled because styles is the default but fails the tests because styles does not have access to the named exports.

rollup config.js

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import postCssConfig from '@cinch-labs/postcss-config'
import pkg from './package.json'
import { designTokens, toJSON } from './src/tokens'

const extensions = ['.ts', '.tsx']

// stylelint does work but the postcss one needed to be removed
const postcssPlugins = postCssConfig(toJSON(designTokens)).filter(
  ({ postcssPlugin }: { postcssPlugin: string }) => postcssPlugin !== 'stylelint',
)

export default [
  {
    input: './src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'cjs',
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: 'es',
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        modules: true,
        extract: false,
        syntax: 'postcss-scss',
        plugins: postcssPlugins,
        use: ['sass'],
      }),
      resolve({
        extensions,
      }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: 'tsconfig.rollup.json' }),
      terser(),
    ],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
  },
]
```

test.component.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames'

// I expected the bundler to resolve this for me...
import * as styles from './text.module.scss'

import { TextProps } from './text.types'

export const Text: React.FC<TextProps> = ({
  children,
  fontSize = 'm',
  fontWeight = 'medium',
  fontStyle = 'normal',
  lineHeight = 'body',
  element = 'p',
  className,
  ...props
}) => {
  const HtmlEl = element

  const classes = classNames(
    {
      [styles[`textSize${fontSize.toUpperCase()}`]]: fontSize,
      [styles[`textWeight${fontWeight.toUpperCase()}`]]: fontWeight,
      [styles[`textLineHeight${lineHeight.toUpperCase()}`]]: lineHeight,
      [styles[`textFontStyle${fontStyle.toUpperCase()}`]]: fontStyle,
    },
    className,
  )

  // classes returns undefined when bundled because of commonjs format.

  return (
    <HtmlEl className={classes} {...props}>
      {children}
    </HtmlEl>
  )
}
```

I know this is due to the way common JS works however I would expect for the import * as styles to work. When I change it to `import styles from './text.module.scss'` it works fine when bundled but does not work in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Using `import * as styles from './text.module.scss'` you are importing the styles as a named export.
Since this also returns `{default: {... my class names} }`, you can use `styles.default` instead, or, perhaps, assign it to a new variable like
`const style = styles.default`

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this issue was by doing `import styles from 'path name'` and then installing jest-css-modules to map the styles object in my test.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-css-modules

Answer (score 0):

for me to compile and include with rollup.js the scss into the bundle/build worked adding:

```
plugins: [
      postcss({
        modules: true,
        extract: false,
        syntax: 'postcss-scss',
        use: ['sass'],
      }),
],
```

Hope this will help someone else in this journey :)